# Calling a Rest API with the username, password, company ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to rest api's and calling them via .NET MVC

I have an api:

```
{
                "name": "Create Statistical Journal Entry\n",
                "request": {
                    "url": "{{temp_session_endpoint}}",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "header": [
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/xml",
                            "description": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "body": {
                        "mode": "raw",
                        "raw": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<request>\n  <control>\n    <senderid>{{sender_id}}</senderid>\n    <password>{{sender_password}}</password>\n    <controlid>{{$timestamp}}</controlid>\n    <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>\n    <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>\n    <includewhitespace>false</includewhitespace>\n  </control>\n  <operation>\n    <authentication>\n      <sessionid>{{temp_session_id}}</sessionid>\n    </authentication>\n    <content>\n      <function controlid=\"{{$guid}}\">\n        <create>\n          <GLBATCH>\n            <JOURNAL>SHC</JOURNAL>\n            <BATCH_DATE>03/31/2016</BATCH_DATE>\n            <BATCH_TITLE>Headcount 03/31/2016</BATCH_TITLE>\n            <ENTRIES>\n              <GLENTRY>\n                <ACCOUNTNO>HEADS</ACCOUNTNO>\n                <DEPARTMENT>ADMIN</DEPARTMENT>\n                <LOCATION>100</LOCATION>\n                <TR_TYPE>1</TR_TYPE>\n                <AMOUNT>2.00</AMOUNT>\n                <DESCRIPTION>Headcount 03/31/2016</DESCRIPTION>\n              </GLENTRY>\n            </ENTRIES>\n          </GLBATCH>\n        </create>\n      </function>\n    </content>\n  </operation>\n</request>\n"
                    },
                    "description": ""
                },
                "response": []
            }
```

The notes for the api say that to authorize I need to use the below credentials - how do I do that?

```
    <authentication>
  <login>
    <userid>{{user_id}}</userid>
    <companyid>{{company_id}}{{temp_slide_in}}</companyid>
    <password>{{user_password}}</password>
  </login>
</authentication>
```

I currently have this code:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("sessionid", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user_id" + ":" + "company_id" + ":"+ "password")));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
```

However I get a 401 unauthorized error.

What am I missing, how do I authenticate api calls using these credentials?

Comment: "*how do I form api calls using these credentials*" -- this is entirely dependent on the API authors. We don't have the luxury of reading the API documentation or reading their minds. In short, without turning this into wild guessing game with prizes and stuff, its extremely hard to help you.

Comment: @TheGeneral I have all the credentials which they required but the only thing is I am confused how to pass those credentials. I have seen the examples where we can pass the user ID and password but here I need to pass the company ID as well which makes me confused as how to pass that parameter while authenticating this API.